# How do I copy all gnome-keyring items to a different computer?

Tags: security, backup, passwords, restore, gnome-keyring

I keep snapshots of my home directory using rsync (with --link-dest, fyi). I haven't used my desktop in a while, so I used rsync to 'restore' my laptop snapshot over my desktop home directory. I didn't think about what would happen to my keyring. `.local/share/keyrings` got overwritten. Which is not that big a deal, because I have a backup, but I have a lot of new stuff that I can't just rsync into the old keyrings. Is there an rsync for keyrings, that would take a source keyring location and password, and copy everything to the destination keyring location and password? I'm basically wishing for:

```
keyring-sync -uv /backup_snapshot/.local/share/keyrings ~/.local/share/keyrings
```

Alternatively (and less ideally), if I could change the password of a copy of the source keyrings, I could just change it to the desktop password and overwrite the desktop keyrings with that copy.